# How to load more posts using ajax with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

I am trying to load more posts on the index page of my website. I came up with something like this

A button that does an AJAX call to back-end to change the limit of the mysql query:

```
    $("body").on('click','#loadMore',function(){ 
    var loadMoreBtn = $('#loadMore');
    var ajaxLimit = 5;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            method: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'application/json',
            data:{ajaxLimit:ajaxLimit},
            success: function(response){ 
            console.log("limit changed")
            }
        });
});
```

and on the back-end I have a variable called limit that I add the ajaxLimit to:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
var ajaxLimit = req.body.ajaxLimit;
var limit = 10 + ajaxLimit ;

var q ="SELECT posts.post_title, posts.image, posts.post_description, posts.id, DATE_FORMAT(posts.created_at, '%m/%d/%Y') AS created_at, users.avatar, users.username, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM comments WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id) AS NumberOfComments, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM likes WHERE likes.post_id = posts.id) AS NumberOfLikes FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT "+ limit + "";
connection.query(q, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var post_id = results[0].id;
    res.render("t_index",{posts:results});
});
});
```

What I will do next is append the new posts to the current view. But I am not able to change the limit, I believe I am doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter **req.body.ajaxLimit** comes in as string so cast it to an int to have the limit that you want.

```
var ajaxLimit = parseInt(req.body.ajaxLimit)
```

Comment: Sweet now I can change the limit. Do you know where I can look for to append the data to the index page after the ajax call?